# How do I configure PostgreSQL with Grails 3.0?

Tags: java, postgresql, grails, jdbc, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2 as an IDE. I have created a Grails 3.0 application and changed it a bit to configure PostgreSQL.

Here is my dataSource:

```
dataSource:
pooled: true
jmxExport: true
driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
username: postgres
password: root

environments:
development:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/trace_db
test:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/trace_db
production:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/trace_db
        properties:
            jmxEnabled: true
            initialSize: 5
            maxActive: 50
            minIdle: 5
            maxIdle: 25
            maxWait: 10000
            maxAge: 600000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
            validationQuery: SELECT 1
            validationQueryTimeout: 3
            validationInterval: 15000
            testOnBorrow: true
            testWhileIdle: true
            testOnReturn: false
            jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
            defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

And in my `build.gradle` I added `runtime "postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1207.jdbc4"`.

But that gives errors when I run:

```
ERROR org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: org.postgresql.Driver
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Do you have the postgresql JDBC driver on the classpath?

Comment: Please accept one answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data source

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    username = "postgres"
    password = "xxx"
```

Build Config

```
dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        runtime "org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1208.jre7"
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    }
```

Change the jre number according to your db numbe psql version.
Hope i helped. Cheers!

Comment: You saved a life! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a tab missing in your configuration

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: root
```

Everything after datasource needs to be indented.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a Grails 4/5 version of this:
`implementation "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.2"`

```
dataSource:
pooled: true
jmxExport: true
driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
username: postgres
password: ''
```

and finally

```
url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it was answered but I found that using the application.yml was not giving me access to the datasource configuration, instead it assumed the H2 Driver.

build.gradle (only dependencies block):

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
compile "org.grails:grails-core"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"

runtime "postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1208-atlassian-hosted"

compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.4"

console "org.grails:grails-console"
profile "org.grails.profiles:web:3.1.6"
runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.8.2"

testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
```

Erased everything related to database from application.yml and instead used the application.groovy:

```
dataSource{
    pooled= true
    jmxExport=true
    driverClassName= 'org.postgresql.Driver'
    username= 'xxxx'
    password= 'xxxx'    }

environments{   
    development{
        dataSource{
            dbCreate= 'create-drop'
            url= "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xxx"
            logSql= true
            hibernate.default_schema= "template_dm" 
        }
    }
    test{
        dataSource{
            dbCreate= 'create-drop'
            url= "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xxx"
            logSql= true
            hibernate.default_schema= "template_dm" 
        }
    }
    production{
        dataSource{
            dbCreate= 'create-drop'
            url= "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xxx"
            logSql= true
            hibernate.default_schema= "template_dm" 
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps everyone with the same issue.

Cheers

Answer (score -2):

Run the Grails application using `grails run-app` instead of running it through IntelliJ. I had this [issue too with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36206683/setting-up-grails-3-1-0-with-mysql/36207272).

I still haven't figured out how to get to work properly through IntelliJ, but at least it works when you use the Grails console!

Note: this is assuming you already have the JDBC driver set up properly. I had mine set up properly for MySQL and kept digging around, thinking that I'd set it up wrong somehow.